# unit test - Verify method of a child object is called

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am new to unit test and current I have a problem to verify a method of a child object of the current object. Is it even possible? I'm using C#/NUnit/Moq

What I would like to do would be like:

```
_myProperty.setup(x=>x.child.someMether(It.IsAny<string>)).Verifiable();
```

Thanks for your time to read my question.

Comment: Is the method `someMether` abstract in the parent so that it's required to exist in all children?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
_myProperty.Verify(x=>x.child.someMether(It.IsAny<string>)),Times.Once())
```

Try the above. It will verify that a method was called Once